# Hide unhide item category JavaScript code is not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I have a MySQL table as "stores_item_category" in my project which included some of item categories as follows:

```
+----+--------------+--------+
| id |   category   | status |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | Electronic   |      1 |
|  2 | Electric     |      1 |
|  3 | Furniture    |      1 |
|  4 | Vehicle      |      1 |
|  5 | Fixed Assets |      1 |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

Controller included following code in related to the above data.

```
public function addInventoryItems()
{
    $category =  $this->input->post('category');
    $data =  $this->Item_model->getInventoryProductsByCategory($category);
    echo $data;
}
```

And used the following JavaScript code to select that categories through a view named "stock_update".

```
if(category == 1 || category == 2) {
    $('#serial_no').next(".select2-container").show();
    $("#qty").hide();
    $('table th').eq(4).text( 'Serial No' );
    $('table td').eq(4).css("width", "50%")
} else {
    $('#serial_no').next(".select2-container").hide();
    $('table th').eq(4).text( 'Quantity' );
    
    $('#serial_no').val(null).trigger('change');
    $("#qty").prop('type', 'number');
    $("#qty").show();
    $('table td').eq(4).css("width", "10%")
}
```

The view also included some of another fields in addition to the category field. All other parts are working properly. The view includes another field as "serial_no" which used the following HTML code.

```
<td  id="headerQty">
    <select name="serial_no0[]" id="serial_no" class="serial_no form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%"></select>
    <input type="hidden" step="any" name="qty0" id="qty" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" style="width: 100%"/>
</td>
```

In here, I want show the "serial_no" field, if I select the item category "Electronic" or "Electric". Otherwise the field name "serial_no" should be hide in my view.

But the existing code did not out the desired result. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Where is the class `.select2-container` I only see a `.select2` class

Comment: @ RiggsFolly. Yes that I was missed